# How to find out if dragging started in a different browser tab

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

In this example,

```
document.body.addEventListener("drop", function ($event) {

}
```

how to find out from the $event if dragging of the element that is dropped started in a different browser tab?

Comment: Not without some really hacky stuff. You'd probably need to involve a backend and perhaps a websocket connection.

Answer (score 0):

any element has `ownerDocument` property.

Try this: `target.ownerDocument === document`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless you own the code in both tabs. You can use `window.postmessage`. I believe you also need to open the second tab from the first with JavaScript to start the possibility of communication with `window.open`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Inside the drop event, you would `postmessage` to the other window. That window must be listening to such events.

Your other option would be again to own the code in both tabs and you could send messages over the network/backend. I have done this with VR games where two clients are interacting with the same objects but in your case, the 2 clients would be the same client.